# How to implement autoplay functionality only on UIScrollView?

Tags: uiscrollview, focus, autoplay

[image]In scrollview did scrolling and focus view video is playing and all are video is pause.
How can I implement this functionality?

I get center and top position of UIScrollView() but top video is play when focused but all are video also playing, so how can I implement only focus video is play using scrollview?